# Linux kernel SCTP vulnerability

Tags: debian, security

Linux kernel is hit with 2 remote dos [vulnerabilities](http://www.debian.org/security/2010/dsa-2126) and like all good admins the kernel should be upgraded. But is there any immediate steps we can take (eg: disable SCTP) which can mitigate the effect of this kernel vulnerabilities, till the time we upgrade and reboot all servers? Also how can we check if our kernel is really vulnerable?

with regards,

raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any SCTP service?  if no, then there's nothing to disable and you're safe.  If yes, then patch ASAP

Comment: i have never deployed any thing which specefically requires SCTP. The servers are running standard postfix/apache etc, nothing fancy. So i guess i am safe for now.